# Android AsyncTask helper class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I currently have a class UserFunctions that does all my user actions e.g. register, login etc. In the UserFunctions class there's a JSONParser object that does all the actual HTTP calls and returns the JSONObject.

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    private static String registerURL = Constants.registerUrl;

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions(){
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    public JSONObject register(){
        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL);
        // return json
        return json;
    }
...
}
```

and then in my event handler of my activity classes I just do UserFunctions.register().

My question is, I now want to do all these calls in a background thread and at the same time show a ProgressDialog. I know running in the background thread is achieved with the AsyncTask.

But how should I achieve this design such that I can still do UserFunctions.register() in my Activity class, everything to be done in a background thread and a progressDialog shown.

Comment: Does the progress dialog have to show actual data or just show loading?

Comment: preferably it shows a unique message based on what is happening, i.e. displays "Registering..." at the registration process and "Logging you in..." etc. but i could live with a generic "Loading..." too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok for this there are two parts the progress dialog and the async task, you need to move your JSONparser into the actual async task. If you want to use multiple progress dialogs just call them before calling the asynctask and close them when it returns

```
private class JsonRetriever extends AsyncTask<Url, Void, JSONObject>{
            private JSONParser jsonParser;
            private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public JsonRetriever(Context c){
        dialog= new ProgressDialog(c);
        jsonParser= new JSONParser();
    }
    protected void onPreExecute() {
          dialog.setMessage("Starting retrieval");
          dialog.show();
    }
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Url... params) {
         try{
            return jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject success) {
             if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                     dialog.dismiss();
            }
      }
}
```

Then to call this just do

```
public JSONObject register(){
    return new JSONRetriever(this).execute(registerURL).get();
}
```

Comment: this sounds like great. will i need to pass it the Context somewhere since my JSONRetriever and UserFunctions are standalone classes and not inner classes?

Comment: If you want to have a progress dialog, you will need to pass the Context of the activity it's in so that Android can know where to open the dialog, Sorry I had thought user functions was an activity for some reason.

Comment: i think i managed to get everything linked up now! 

its working as intended except for one part. after clicking the Register button, it hangs for about 2-3 seconds, and then shows the progressDialog for a split second before immediately moving to the main page.

Comment: Ok so I didn't realise you were calling straight from the activity, by using get() it will turn your async task into a sync task, and block your UI thread. instead call just execute, and then in onPostExecute call something like context.asyctaskcomplete(success), where asynctaskcomplete controls the transition in your activity, also I have updated my code as there was an error as onPostExecute was recieveing a bool instead of a JSONObject.

Comment: hmmm i am trying to study it a bit more now. 

i assume asynctaskcomplete is a self defined method right? so it may involve some casting or i need to create base classes of some sort so that my onPostExecute() can call context.asynctaskcomplete()?

Comment: yes, you would have to create a subclass of context/activity.

Answer (score 1):

Would this help you?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     new MyAsyncTask(this).execute();
}

privateclass MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;

    public ProgressTask(Context context) {
        this.context= context;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        // do you registering or whether here
        // in this model you can return a boolean to the PostExecute.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do as the following:

1)Declare you dialog in activity class like this:

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
```

2)then declare you AsyncTask as below:

```
private class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{
            String nessage="";
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Registering user",
                            "Please wait.....");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                // provide yourcode to register the user then return message
                      return message="you are registered";
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                            if (result.equlas("you are resgisted"))
                             // optinal if you want to do as below
                             // do something here showing toast or any thing of your prefreance  

            }
         }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but this will not allow reusability right? i will need a class that extends AsyncTask for each method i have in UserFunction.

is there a way i can create a generic helper class that extends AsyncTask so that i wont need to create multiple AsyncTask classes?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `publishProgress()` from the [AsyncTask-Class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) i think its what you are looking for.

This method is used for updating the UI, when the Background-Thread done some Work. You can call it when ever you want it in the `doInBackground()`-Method.